# WooCommerce - get_order() doesn't work and it returns zero

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, price

I am creating an online shop with WooCommerce and I'm adding a function which will update the bonus point to my database into `absract-wc-payment-gateway.php`.

Here is what I am doing:

1. Firstly, on the checkout page, the users will click the `place order` button and then the method will get the users bonus points and minus the bonus points with the `get-total()`, and then update to the database and go to the thank you page.

[image]

2. Then, the thank you page will get the user's bonus points from the database. And I set the bonus points value to 2000. So in this case, the bonus points should be minus by total Points($50.00)

[image]

Here is my code. It will be ran when the user clicks the place order button:

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$total = $order->get_total();   
$bonusPoint -= (int)$total; //minus total price and calculate the latest bonus point

$updateSql = "UPDATE userdata02 SET bonusPoint ='" .$bonusPoint.  "' WHERE userID = 2147483647";

mysqli_query($link, $updateSql);// update to an int column

if(mysqli_query($link, $updateSql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error update record: <>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Call the method when the user clicks place button:

```
public function get_return_url( $order = null ) {

    if ( $order ) {
        //$message = "wrong answer";
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        $return_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
    } else {
        $return_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) );
    }

    if ( is_ssl() || get_option('woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout') == 'yes' ) {
        $return_url = str_replace( 'http:', 'https:', $return_url );
    }

    self::reducePoints();  //Call reducePoints();
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_return_url', $return_url, $order );
}
```

The source code: `reducePoints()` lines 89 from [abstract-WC-Payment-Gateway.php](https://gist.github.com/capslock10/0c5f4cd53b957261ceceb2cd619a8c61)

The `get_total()` doesn't work and it returns zero.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the error log why this internal error is occuring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an object for `$order` to  use it  with **`get_total()`**. Try this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$total = $order->get_total(); //Get the total price of the order.
$bonusPoints -= (int)$total; //calculate the new bonusPoints
```

---

**Update1:** This is just solving the internal data error. We need to get the **`$order_id`** to get it work…

Note: You can remove `global $woocommerce;`before `$order = new WC_Order($order_id);` because is already included in `public function reducePoints( ){`

---

**Update2 - The good track:**

Remove my code:

```
global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
```

Then at line 89 of your code just add `$order` in:

```
public function reducePoints( $order ){
    global $woocommerce;

    // ...
```

Really happy that this works… It was a long search...

Comment: I fixed the problem by using `tracks:2`! Love u so much <3